# Why i crushed with "lateinit property injector has not been initialized"?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Learning Dagger 2, do it by Guide.

I create `injector` on my App(extended Application):

```
class App : Application() {
    lateinit var injector: ApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        injector = DaggerApplicationComponent
            .builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(getInstance()))
            .build()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }

        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this)
    }

    companion object {

        private var instance: App? = null

        fun getInstance(): App {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = App()
            }
            return instance as App
        }
    }
}
```

After that, i write on Activity:

```
@Inject
lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        App.getInstance().injector.inject(this)
        mainPresenter.init(this)
        mainPresenter.getData()
    }
```

And crushed. What do i wrong?

ApplicationComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

    val db: TestDatabase
}
```

My applicationModule is big, i want to do many things on one module while learning. Here it is:

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val app: App) {

    private var db: EmployeeDatabase = Room
        .databaseBuilder(
            app,
            TestDatabase::class.java,
            TestDatabase.DATABASE_NAME.plus(".db")
        )
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): App {
        return app
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMainViewPresenter(): MainPresenter = MainPresenter(db)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    internal fun providesRoomDatabase(): EmployeeDatabase {
        return db
    }
}
```

MainPresenter:

```
class MainPresenter @Inject constructor(private var db: TestDatabase) {

    private var mainActivity: MainView? = null
    private val apiService = ApiService.create()

    fun init(mainView: MainView) {
        mainActivity = mainView
    }

    fun getData() {
        ...some database logic
    }

    fun onDestroy() {
        mainActivity = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Your application module is very, very, very small. Don't worry. What does App.getInstance() do? You are not supposed to get the current app instance like that. share the whole code if you want help

Comment: Ok, i extended my answer, added code on `App` class, extended MainActivity and added presenter. Another classes are completed. It's too large code, so i afraid nobody will read it, so i cut it. =)

Comment: Add the stacktrace of the crash, we have no idea what the error is!

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance = this
```

And also you should replace the `getInstance()` with just `instance!!` because you should not try to create your own `App` instance.